# Is there any way to combine the logs of lambda exporting to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using lambda cloudwatch log S3 export.

After this command ,there comes many short files.

However I want to combine the files into one.

I can not use aws-cli for our regulation.

When exporting, or in S3 anywhere OK.

Is there any good way to combine the lambda log into one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can utilize Kinesis Firehose for that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/writing-with-cloudwatch-logs.html). You can set buffer size (file size that, when reached, will be written to S3) and buffer interval (time after which the data in Firehose will be written to S3). When one of the requirements is reached (buffer size or interval), the file will be written to S3.